# Accessing MathJax CDN from China

Tags: support

I have been trying to access the site from China and it seems that MathJax cdn is inaccessible from here due to the Great Firewall. All the math content on the site looks pretty odd to look at. I tried adding mathjax to my blog to check if I am having the same problem and it seems so. Are other users from China facing the same problem? Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: not an expert here, but IIRC, you can install the fonts (and maybe a few more things) on your computer once for all and then there would be need for the cdn. Check MathJax website.

Comment: unfortunately mathjax domain is blocked so no access to the site and hence the CDN as well. But it is a good idea. I will find a way to do it...

Comment: This has been going on for a while apparently: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/latex-is-not-properly-displayed

Comment: wait, right now I'm in Beijing, and I don't have any problems at all with mathjax. But what's exactly your problem, accessing the mathjax website or rendering math in cstheory? Because in my case I cand do both.

Comment: It started working today.. Lucky day :)